# Put img on the border of two divs

Tags: html, css

I would like to place my logo on the border of two divs. I've two questions:

1. In which div should I place this logo: in div above or in div below or maybe put in another div?
2. How can I position it. I tried absolute and relative but it doesn't work.

It should looks like:
[image]

**HTML**

```
<!-- Favorites -->
    <section class="favorites">
        <h2 class="favorites-header">Urban Favorites</h2>
        <div class="favorites-box">
            <img src="img/burger-craft-burgers-e1497746930767.png">
               <div class="favorites-info">
                <h2>Craft Your Own Burger</h2>
                <p>Always get exactly what you want with this build-your-own classic. Always get exactly what you want with this build-your-own classic.</p>
               </div>
        </div>
        <div class="favorites-box-last">
            <img src="img/burger-craft-fries.jpg">
            <div class="favorites-info">
            <h2>Loaded Cheese Fries</h2>
            <p>Always get exactly what you want with this build-your-own classic. Always get exactly what you want with this build-your-own classic.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Here is my logo --> <img class="favorites-logo" src="img/urban8-logo-shadow.png" alt="logo-shadow">
    </section>

    <!-- Review -->
    <section class="review">
        <div class="review-element">
            <p>"Great meals!"</p>
            <img src="img/five-stars.png">
            <p>-Jane Doe</p>
        </div>
        <div class="review-element">
            <p>"Awesome atmosphere!"</p>
            <img src="img/five-stars.png">
            <p>-Aicia Fox</p>
        </div>
        <div class="review-element">
            <p>"Everything is ok"</p>
            <img src="img/five-stars.png">
            <p>-Cesar Algir</p>
        </div>
        <button>Leave a Review</button>
    </section>
```

Comment: Can you post the styles that you tried with absolute/relative?

Comment: Please create a working jsfiddle or codepen with all relevant html, css and working image(s) so people can help.

Comment: put it in the top div and use  negative margin-bottom or put it in the bottom div and use negative margin-top

Comment: Ok guys, I got it!

Comment: I would have done it differently .. This is my take .. http://jsfiddle.net/56j1xaew/8/